# Not loading flash crossdomain.xml, bad request

Tags: flash, apache-flex, security

Hi I have a Windows Server 2003, with a domain: "mydomain.com" and everything goes right until the Flash application tries to load de crossdomain.xml, because it tries to load it from "servername" and obviously the request fails.

Currently I have read all about crossdomain.xml , what it is, where it goes although I can not find what I have to do so my flash application requests the crossdomain.xml from my domain "mydomain.com" and not from my server "servername".

Thanks a lot and any help would be very appreciated.

Notes:
- The domain is up and can be accessed from the internet
- The crossdomain is on the root folder and also can be accessed from the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crossdomain.xml is used when a flash movie requests resources from a host different from the one the swf file is hosted on.

So if you swf is on mydomain.com it will not need a crossdomain file for any files on that server.

But if your swf on mydomain.com loads an image or file from otherDomain.com, it will ask the otherdomain.com server for the crossdomain file.

The crossdomain.xml file should usually be places in the root of otherDomain.com

In advanced configurations you can place the crossdomain.xml file in a specific folder, but this is not the typical case.

In cases when you cannot load the files from a domain because do you not contain it, such as when using Facebook Profile Images, you will have to use serverside scripts to proxy the files.

Comment: +1; I had no idea a crossdomain.xml could be in a file other than the root folder.  Do you have docs on that?

Comment: Its in the Crossdomain Policy File spec. Its a PDF (sorry) and its in section 1.4.2
http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/download/attachments/64389123/CrossDomain_PolicyFile_Specification.pdf?version=1

Answer (score 0):

The only reason a SWF would try to load a crossdomain.xml file from "servername" is because the SWF is requesting data from "servername".  The only way this would happen if the SWF was loaded from "mydomain.com" would be if 'servername' was hardcoded somewhere.

I would look for that "hard coded" reference.  Keep in mind it is not explicitly stored as code in the SWF.  IT could be part of a services-config file or part of dynamic data loaded from a server or config file that defines remote servers which must be accessed.